# Is there a way to get the scrollbar height and width?

Tags: c#, .net, listview, scrollbar

I'm trying to get the height and width of the scrollbars that are displayed on a ListView.  Is there an easy way to do this?  I did some google'ing and it looks like it might be a system setting. I'm just not sure where to look.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, it is a system setting.  Use [SystemInformation.HorizontalScrollBarHeight](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.horizontalscrollbarheight?view=netframework-4.7.2) and [SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.verticalscrollbarwidth?view=netframework-4.7.2).

> **Namespace**: System.Windows.Forms

Answer (score 7):

On .Net CF, where `SystemInformation.HorizontalScrollBarHeight` and `SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth` don't exist, some P/Invoke is required:

```
public sealed class Native
{
    public static Int32 GetVerticalScrollbarWidth()
    {
        return GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXVSCROLL);
    }

    public Int32 GetHorizontalScrollbarHeight()
    {
        return GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYHSCROLL);
    }

    [DllImport("coredll.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern Int32 GetSystemMetrics(Int32 index);

    public const Int32
        SM_CXVSCROLL = 2,
        SM_CYHSCROLL = 3;
}
```